# Name of window from tray

Tags: windows, tray

I have a rather unusual question, namely, how is called this window from icon tray?

[image]

I would like to make it in my application, and I could not find his name. I would ask for some information, or the name, the rest I should have to deal with.

Comment: There's nothing special about it, it is just a plain window.  You can create one in Winforms, set ControlBox = False, Text = "" and BackColor = White.  Writing the code for OnPaint() is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows UX Guidelines don't say anything about it. From my perspective it's just a normal dialog, albeit one that has rather immediate actions (as opposed to first clicking on an OK button of sorts) and resides in a fairly small size in a specific location. It is meant to be opened, interacted with quickly and then dismissed, never being the center of your attention. If your idea fits those criteria as well, then go ahead. It's easy to recreate with standard means.